# Open a specific Google Sheet sub-sheet using the googledrive url scheme and the iOS Sheets App

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-sheets

Is it possible to link to a *specific sub-sheet* in the Sheets app for iOS using the googledrive:// or googlesheets:// URL scheme?

Using the URL and querystring parameter (gid=) displayed in the browser doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: ...Surprised that in half a year, nobody has any idea.  I've been looking for a way to do this too.

Answer (score 2):

**There is unfortunately no options to open a *specific sub-sheet* using the url scheme**

To open a *specific sheet* in the Google Sheet app for iOS you can use the URL scheme for Google Sheets (googlesheets://). Insert the URL address for the *specific sheet* after the last slash.

**In Safari**

```
googlesheets://https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...
```

**Objective-C code**

```
NSString *url = @"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"googlesheets://%@",url];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
```

**Swift code**

```
let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/..."
let string = NSURL(string : "googlesheets://\(url)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(string!)
```

This will work if you only want to open a *specific sheet*

Comment: Ah, but was looking for a way not within an iOS app.

Comment: Type this into Safari on iOS and Google Sheets app will open   googlesheets://

Comment: yep, i even mentioned that in the question above.  the question is to get it to open to a specific subsheet.